# Filter Json by date in LogicApp

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have the following json which is built in a logic app, however the final result must be only the objects with a maximum date, that is, the final result must be only one record per object with the maximum date of that object.

```
[{
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T14:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "PartOrder"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T21:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "PartOrder"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T14:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "PartOrderItem"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T17:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Engineer"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T13:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Engineer"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T03:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T05:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T06:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T07:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T10:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T12:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T13:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T15:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T16:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T17:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T18:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T19:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T20:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T22:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T03:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T04:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T05:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T06:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T07:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T09:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T10:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T12:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T13:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T14:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T15:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T19:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T20:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T21:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T22:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T23:00:07.8451571Z",
    "CollectionName": "Task"
}, {
    "CollectionName": "PartOrder",
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T00:00:07.8451571Z"
}, {
    "CollectionName": "PartOrderItem",
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T00:00:07.8451571Z"
}, {
    "CollectionName": "PartsInStock",
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T00:00:07.8451571Z"
}, {
    "CollectionName": "Engineer",
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T00:00:07.8451571Z"
}, {
    "CollectionName": "Task",
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T00:00:07.8451571Z"
}
```

]

The expected result should be one record per object with the max date obtained in the initial json:

```
[{
    "CollectionName": "PartOrder",
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T21:00:07.8451571Z"
}, {
    "CollectionName": "PartOrderItem",
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T14:00:07.8451571Z"
}, {
    "CollectionName": "PartsInStock",
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-13T00:00:07.8451571Z"
}, {
    "CollectionName": "Engineer",
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T13:00:07.8451571Z"
}, {
    "CollectionName": "Task",
    "FechaUltimaCarga": "2020-09-14T23:00:07.8451571Z"
}
```

]

How can I get this result?

I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I designed a azure logic app workflow for you:

You can convert Json to an array, and then use the [Filter array action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#filter-array-action) to filter out the array items whose `CollectionName` is equal to `PartOrder`

[image]

Then you can use the [Select action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#select-action) to fetch the value of `FechaUltimaCarga`, use the [inline code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code) to execute the js code to compare dates, and the result will return the maximum value of the dates.

[image]

Then you use `for each` to traverse your json array, and use the `condition` action within `for each` to add eligible items to the empty array created earlier.

[image]

You need to repeat the above operation, because you also need to filter the array items whose `CollectionName` is equal to `PartOrderItem`, `PartsInStock`...

Finally, you can directly convert the resulting array into a string, which is the json value you want.

[image]

I did a test, but only filtered the array items whose `CollectionName` is equal to `PartOrder`, and the result is the expected value. You can complete the logic app workflow according to my logic.

[image]

**Note**

Implementation of inline code requires [Integration accounts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-enterprise-integration-create-integration-account).

Comment: The solution is great, but I don't have an integration account for the java script code activity

Comment: Please refer to the last link in my answer, you can create a free Integration accounts on the azure portal according to the official documentation. If you still can't understand after reading the official documentation, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I had already seen the link but due to the guidelines of the company where I work, we do not have permissions to create this type of resources

Comment: Of course, if it's a great solution that you've provided, I'll keep looking to fine-tune it without this integration account.

Thank you very much Frank Gong